# A way to exclude folder and subfolder routing in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

i have a simple PWA in public folder in Laravel 9 app.

the folder structures is like this

```
-public
--index.php
--pwa
---index.html
---assets etc etc
```

now when i access directly my application via **localhost/pwa**, it works fine, but when i access sublinks etc like **localhost/pwa/something/something**, Laravel will catch up the route and serve 404

now i know there are solutions involving editing server configs ( nginx/apache ) but i want to know if there is any pure Laravel/PHP solution.

something like

> `Route::exclude('/pwa/*')`

to totally exclude/ignore routes that matches it

Comment: You will need to edit server configs regardless. So no point in dealing those in Laravel routes way.

Comment: But the original route localhost/pwa is being handle just fine in the first place.. i mean, pretty sure laravel handles it and redirect it to public folder..

Comment: You can remove .htaccess and try again. It should treat localhost/pwa as a route too.

Comment: i did my dev using php artisan serve command.. so no htaccess here.. and accessing localhost/pwa is fine... what is not fine is when accessing localhost/pwa/something..
interestingly.. if i make a dummy folder to simulate the routing.. then it works.. that proves that laravel routing check either it matches any folder in public and then check in web.php ( or vice versa )

Comment: Those rules are written in .htaccess.

Comment: I forgot that when using artisan serve, it directly handle the public folder.. so php server must see the folder pwa first and handles it.. then serve the index.php if no folder exist.. so thats means my only option is to change the server config